# Generate table-unique string

Tags: php, mysql

So basically this

I want to have a 5 character long string/token with each row of my table

Each token is comprised of these characters

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Creating the token isn't the issue, making it unique is

I know I could create a token, check if it exists, and loop until it doesnt but that seems really inefficient and that could possibly be a lot of queries

Is there a cleaner, faster solution to this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of this token?

Comment: @Uueerdo an alternate, public identifier for the row

Comment: without just incrementing or rotating the value in some way, there is no way to tell if the string you generated is unique. You could pre-fill a table of all possible values (or a bunch of random unique ones), select one and delete it (or mark another column as used).

Comment: As long as you are not using the identifier for internal linking of data, I see no reason to limit it to 5 characters; it sounds like a pretty good candidate for GUID use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just generate a random number between 0 and 60466175, check if it exists, and then `CONV([the number], 10, 36)`.

The chances of collision are very dependent on how much data you have, if it seems like it will be a problem, a solution might be to stuff all 60 million+ combinations into a table ahead of time, with a `used` field. Pick one `where used = 0` at random, and mark it as used at that time.

Edit: Another user's comment to the original question is even better, deleting from an "available tokens" table would mean speed could improve with time.

Edit2: If you want to ensure exactly 5 digits, the number must be >= 1679616.

Answer (score 0):

This can be what you are looking for:

https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317

```
var ID = function () {
  // Math.random should be unique because of its seeding algorithm.
  // Convert it to base 36 (numbers + letters), and grab the first 9 characters
  // after the decimal.
  return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
```

If you are willing to use js libraries then:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

http://hashids.org/

Comment: Sorry, but what you linked is completely useless in my situation :P
Creating the tokens isn't the issue, finding a good efficient way to make sure they are unique is what I'm trying to find

Comment: You can add a 'timestamp' to your string. But anyway why your string has to be 5 chars long. There is any reason for that?

Comment: There are some solutions out there, check the posted links.